# Can't Able to Add In-App Products at Google Play Console

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have uploaded a new AAB file with an in-app purchase-related setup implemented within the game project.

[image]

Still, I was getting this kind of message at Google Play Console when I try to add in-app products.
[image]

Now what I require to do?

AAB file will not work in this case!! 
I can't able to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uploaded an APK file at Play store console:
[image]

It has enabled me to create in-app products:
[image]

So the problem was resolved :)

But one question raised why it was not worked with AAB file?
This game has already been released in the Play store a few days ago and now we have decided to add in-app products within it.

Before I have only uploaded only AAB files and it worked properly and the game got released.
But when I decided to create in-app products it forced me to upload one APK file.

This is my side overall conclusion regarding this matter.